# Mail Merge Multiple IF Conditions for cell

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, conditional-statements

I have a conditional statement for two cases (and default) which works fine.
This is simply to enter a cell value based on another cell value in an earlier column

simplified and shorm of extraneous stuff I have

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD  Code } = "SITE" {=1}
  IF { MERGEFIELD  Code } = "SUB" {=2}
   {MERGEFIELD  Quantity  }}}
```

But I cannot extend it to three (or more)  "IF"s

Starting from the simplistic

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD  Code } = "SITE" {=1}
  IF { MERGEFIELD  Code } = "SUB" {=2}
  IF { MERGEFIELD  Code } = "OTHER" {=3}
   {MERGEFIELD  Quantity  }}}
```

and progressing through many many approaches with no success .

I presume this is possible - so what havent i grasped !

Comment: The code you have shown would not work because it should have a pair of the special field code braces around each complete IF statement. So it is difficult to see what is wrong with what you have. Are the {=1} actually references to specific cells? If so, can you provide the code you have rather than a "simplified" version.

Comment: Sorry just returned to the issue  Yes the codebraces was the problem  (and the enormous complexity of my statements)   But  what an awful way to have to do things and its been like this it seems forever ! Shame on MS!